# What does inverse element mean in Groups and Vector Spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

This [Groups and Vector Spaces course](https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/vDv_IBtCEeiWORIdrorXgg_bc6c0f301b4211e8a1721fb14d2c5cb9_vector_spaces.pdf?Expires=1562716800&Signature=ZfRO69H9gE1UJcuVkxR0pGy8S2FAy6TyxxJ1Tm8L34Vm8~BM0ziHnyInFsAvLOMUhbWpaobzGAbWYlK4Wrro1vd9TBXakUw~aajGsCw7uD8ci6OPU4G~nYmH3gnek89MTXAWwrRRAxMWOhGBXVgP3dtD6polAS3n4Sgn7CorLj4_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) confuses me.

> Groups play an important role in computer science. Besides providing a
>   fundamental framework for operations on sets, they are heavily used in
>   cryptography, coding theory and graphics.

[image]

why is $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ a group? what is the inverse element to meet the definition condition?

Comment: The inverse of the number $n \neq 0$ here is $-n$. Have a think why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $n \in \Bbb Z$ you have $-n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $n + (-n) = 0$, which is the (additive) identity.

Comment: it must equal zero on RHS

Comment: @george Yep, thanks

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst thanks for your comments, what does `RHS` mean?

Comment: right hand side

Comment: Right hand side

Comment: @Ruben thanks for your answer. in this case, $x = -n$ , $y=n$ and $e=0$, so $x ⊗ y = n + (-n) = 0 $, is understanding right?

Comment: For $0\in\mathbb{Z}$ is also true that $0+(-0)=0$.